# How can we determine unique users participating in an Area51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, user-accounts

I have been active on Area51 for a while now, and I don't think this has ever been a real concern before.

Some background.

In July of this year I noticed that [unless blatantly obvious, multiple accounts on Area 51 go unnoticed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17291).  There are some [known issues with voting that are essentially waiting for Area52 to solve.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13486)

Now along comes the [Pastafarianism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67458) proposal, it is getting lots of attention and votes, in fact when I counted (*I have enough rep to see up & down votes*) earlier this month it had over 800 votes.  The votes have been distributed with a intent towards the impacting the requirement of "40 questions with a score of 10 or more".  While it is unclear if [one person can derail a site proposal on Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17560), I am not sure how many actual unique users (people) are participating in the site proposal.

In a perfect Area 51 proposal it takes 400 votes & 60 followers to move from definition to commitment phase. As there is a limit of 5 up votes per account the site potentially has over 100 active supports (there is around 500+ upvotes) which is a great place to be moving into the commitment phase.

I have considered asking for special consideration to move the Pastafarianism proposal to the next phase. The proposal is 5 months old, and appears to have the basic support and detail required at this point. But I am not sure how much of the activity represents real & unique people, which is what is needed when the site enters beta (after commitment phase).

I am looking for a tool/method to determine what the actual unique live body count is of people who are participating in one specific Area51 proposal. I don't care if they are voting up or down, or how many accounts they have.  I just want to know bodies (IP's maybe?) that posted a question, cast a vote, or followed the proposal.

Comment: Looks like some [housekeeping has occurred](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/14073/why-are-people-opposing-pastafarian-se/18099#18099) this request may not be as critical as I was beginning to believe.